# Caching AJAX results with PHP

Tags: php, jquery

I have an AJAX call that retrieves lines from file via JSON. I have 3M rows in my database and I want to show result but I cannot see anything.

The results retrieved via JSON I wanted to cache, so that if a data is requested more than once, I will not send request again. What is the best practices for caching in jQuery?

I use PHP in my server side. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

My JavaScript code:

```
function GetSearchResult(Char,Company,Category,Country,Page)
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "CompanyResult.php",
        data: {
            mySearchChar : Char,
            mySearchCompany : Company,
            mySearchCategory : Category,
            mySearchCountry : Country,
            myPage : Page
              },
        cache: false,
        dataType : "html",
    beforeSend: function(){
        $("#Loading").show(); //show image loading 
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$('#insid_body_web').offset().top}, 'slow');
        $("#ResultCompany1").hide(); 
        $("#ResultCompany2").hide();
        $("#ErrorSearch").hide(); 
    },
    complete: function(){
       $("#Loading").hide(); //hide image loading
       $("#ResultCompany1").show(); 
       $("#ResultCompany2").show();
       $("#ErrorSearch").hide(); 
    },
    success: function(data){
    $(".insid_body_web").html(data);
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$('#insid_body_web').offset().top}, 'slow');
    $("#ResultCompany1").show();
    $("#ResultCompany2").show(); 
    $("#ErrorSearch").hide();
    $(".insid_body_web").css("min-height","1397px");
    },
    error: function() {
    $("#ErrorSearch").show();
    $("#ResultCompany1").hide();
    $("#ResultCompany2").hide(); 
    },
});
}
```

And PHP function to get result:

```
public function selectallcompanydatabypagingbycat($char,$company,$cat,$country,$from,$records)
{
    $sql ="select company_CompName,company_Phone,company_Site,company_id 
    from company
    where
    company_delete ='0' 
    and company_Request = '0' ";
    if ($cat !=""){ $sql .= " and company_CompCat = '".$cat."' "; }
    if ($company !=""){ $sql .= " and company_CompName = '".$company."' "; }
    if ($country !=""){ $sql .= " and company_country = '".$country."' "; }
    if ($char !=""){ $sql .= " and company_CompName like '".$char."%' "; }
    $sql .= " order by company_id desc limit $from,$records";
    $query = @mysql_query($sql);
    return $query;
    mysql_free_result($query);

}
```

Comment: Please put some effort into your post, show us what did you try with caching and why do you think it doesn't work. Not just your code and ask for someone to write it for you.

Comment: @Puciek i have 3000000 row on database and i wont to show result but i cannot see anything

Comment: Are you untainting your AJAX inputs prior to feeding them into `selectallcompanydatabypagingbycat`? In general I would untaint right inside that method, so it is _always_ done. If you are not untainting, you have a SQL injection in your code.

Comment: So, for clarity, your AJAX call works fine at the moment, and you just want to add client-side caching?

Comment: how can add client-side caching

Comment: Do you want to cache for a specific combination of the five parameters you send to the server in the AJAX call? Should the cache ever expire, or once it has retrieved it for the current session, it should use that result permanently? Should caching survive between page changes (that would necessitate HTML5 storage features) or is caching on a single page enough (that can be done by JavaScript variables)?

Answer (score 0):

Chage your data in the ajax like this

```
 data: {
            "mySearchChar" : Char,
            "mySearchCompany" : Company,
            "mySearchCategory" : Category,
            "mySearchCountry": Country,
            "myPage" : Page
              },
```

And in `CompanyResult.php`

```
$cat = trim($_POST['mySearchCategory']);
$company = trim($_POST['mySearchCompany']);
$country = trim($_POST['mySearchCountry']);
```

......
 and so on...